# Return value of a function from one file to another file in C

Tags: c, epoch

Suppose I have defined a function in `file1.c`. The definition is:

```
#include <time.h>
uint8_t getTime(uint32_t epoch)
{
    time_t rawtime = epoch;
    struct tm *ptm = gmtime(&rawtime);
    return ptm->tm_hour;
}
```

I want to store the return value of the function in a variable in another file `file2.c`. The code is:

```
extern uint8_t getTime(uint32_t epoch);
uint8_t val = getTime(1646648030); //the argument here is extracted from a 32-bit variable
printf("Hour = %d", val);
```

When I try to print the value of `val` I get `0`. Here, I am just trying to get the hour from the epoch time.
What am I missing here?

Comment: Show the code printing `val`

Comment: Please try to create a [mre], and [edit] your question to show it.

Comment: Also, you have tagged this with `embedded`. What is your target hardware and operating-system (if any)? Are you sure the target system support all time and date operations?

Comment: `uint32_t` is not a very future-proof choice for a time value.

Comment: I am just integrating my code with a file which has defined epoch time as 32-bit variable.

Comment: Did you check the value of `ptm->tm_hour` inside the `getTime` function ?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem. I put the `getTime` function in one source file (added `#include <stdint.h>`), then wrote a different source file where I called `getTime` just like you, and it return `10` as expected. Since you now have removed the `embedded` tag, have you tried it on another system? Do you get the same result on e.g. Linux or Windows or a Mac?

Comment: If I am printing `ptm->tm_hour` inside the `getTime` function or in the same file then it prints the value `10`

Comment: Also see [this compiler explorer project](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4b766z4v). Can't replicate your problem. That can only mean that's there's something missing from your question. Either a proper [mre] or details about your exact environment.